# Android Html5 Date Picker Format

Tags: android, html, date, input, format

Developing with Phonegap and JQueryMobile to Android

I'm using the HTML5  control... and I understand why you cannot change the format of DISPLAY (well... not really! but...). I just want to know what Configuration Option do I have to complete in my device because all the options I've checked say "dd-mm-yyyy" and the language is "Spanish" and the location is "Argentina" and all indicates "dd-mm-yyyy" and it keeps DISPLAYING "yyyy-mm-dd"

IMPORTANT: I'm not referring to the .val()!!! That's ok in "yyyy-mm-dd", but the problem is of what is displayed to the user in the HTML Field (not even the Android Picker... that's displaying correctly!)

I cannot make an App to Latin Americans with a Date Field showing "2014-11-23" format... no way!

PS: Is a discrimination case against latins??? hahaha

Answer (score 1):

Displayed Date format depends on device's locale. I suggest to use a div with absolute position that you can update onchange event using the desired format. The div must cover the whole field and onclick you must give the focus to the below field in order to open the native date picker.

Comment: I didn't understand... ;( I just want to know where to configure the "locale" on the device... thanks!

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20599/is-it-posible-to-change-the-locale-of-my-device

Comment: interesting link... it's incredible that you cannot change the locale without a 3rd party App! Thanks!